# Exporting Colors In React using TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, interface

Hey so I am using React with Typescript, and I have created a colors library to store all of our colors so they can be callable by importing LibraryColors and then doing LibraryColors.orange.primary for example. I want this to be easy to use for my team and so I want to give them intellisense when using it. I believe that is possible with an interface but I have no idea what that interface would look like.

```
interface ILibraryColors{

}
const LibraryColors: ILibraryColors = {
    black: {
        primary: "#000000",
    },
    green: {
        light: {
            60: "#40C0C0",
        },
        primary: "#00AEA9",
        dark: {
            40: "#00867C",
        }
    },
    grey: {
        light: {
            80: "#fafafa",
            70: "#dddddd",
            60: "#C4C7C5",
        },
        primary: "#707373",
        dark: {
            40: "#353735"
        }
    },
    orange: {
        light: {
            60: "#FFBB11",
        },
        primary: "#FAA21B",
        dark: {
            40: "#F58220"
        }
    },
    red: {
        light: {
            60: "F15B5D",
        },
        primary: "#E63E51",
        dark: {
            40: "#BC3A4B",
        }
    },
    white: {
        primary: "#ffffff",
    },
    pink: {
        primary: "#f434ed",
    },
    purple: {
        primary: "#1E4286",
    },
    blue: {
        light: {
            60: "#6BC3E7",
        },
        primary: "#06A7E0",
        dark: {
            40: "#005DA6",
        }
    }
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you! Also I know I could forget the primary, dark, and light and simply do 0-100 on the colors, but I think it is easier to remember which way gets lighter and darker this way.

Comment: Can you please fix your title? It gives no information whatsoever about the question. Something along the lines of "Exporting colors in React" would be more informative. I came here expecting a philosophical question on composing higher kinded morphisms in TypeScript or something along those lines...

Comment: I'd suggest to start with a first implementation and then come back and ask if you have a concrete problem. How to write interfaces is explained here https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html - take a look at the index types section for your 80: "xy" properties.

Comment: Sorry about the title, I am new to stack overflow and didn't think about that haha

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
interface IColor {
    [key: number]: string;
}

interface IColorVariant {
    light?: IColor;
    dark?: IColor;
    primary?: string;
}

interface ILibraryColors{
    [key: string]: IColorVariant;
}
```

But if you prefer a more explicit color variant use this:

```
interface IColor {
    10?: string;
    20?: string;
    30?: string;
    40?: string;
    50?: string;
    60?: string;
    70?: string;
    80?: string;
    90?: string;
    100?: string;
}

interface IColorVariant {
    light?: IColor;
    dark?: IColor;
    primary?: string;
}

interface ILibraryColors{
    [key: string]: IColorVariant;
}
```

Comment: Thanks this definitely gets me on the right track! The only thing is that intellisense will  always show 10-100 options regardless of what is actually there. Thanks again though this gives me an awesome starting point, I am new to asking questions on stack overflow so sorry if it is kind of sloppy.

Comment: No problem, ask again if you have any question about this.

Answer (score 0):

```
interface aColor {
  [key: number]: string;
}

interface oColorVariant {
  primary: string;
  light?: aColor;
  dark?: aColor;
}

interface ILibraryColors{
  [key: string]: oColorVariant;
}
```